# prevent of firing Repeater_ItemDataBound event in AspxGridView Edit mode in Row_Updaing Event (Wow!!!)

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress, repeater, aspxgridview

**Hello** everybody !

In .net , i have a Devexpress control [aspxgridview ]... in edit mode of this control , i fill a repeater that has ItemDataBound event

when i press on update btn (of grid) , *itemdatabound* calls & works very well  & i choose an item (is a radioBtn) 

       **BUT**

when i press updateBtn , that event i said (***itemdatabound***) fires again & 
my selected item CLEAR (*i'm crying*)

please help me dears!! 

thanks in advance

mohammad

Answer (score 0):

Since your button is doing a postback, you need to have all items on your page re-created and re-databound in order for them to be displayed. Without having much to go on, it sounds like you need to hold onto your selected item so you can re-create/re-databind the Repeater with every post back.

I may be able to be of more help if you post your code.

Comment: hi dear **shelly** ... thanks 4 ur answer  ... Sorry, but i changed my solution of this phase of project ... i had no enough time ... but if u want , i'll send it 2 U ... thanks Again